# How to pass a data structure like dictionary to call() of LSTM layer?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Suppose, I have a following dictionary constructed as below:

```
od = OrderedDict()
od['a'] = 1
od['b'] = 2
od['c'] = 3
od['d'] = 4
```

and let's say I need to pass this to the LSTM call() function. So, the code for model definition along with other code is as below:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv
import math
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
#from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

# load the dataset
dataframe = read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/airline-passengers.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

# create and fit the LSTM network
# model = Sequential()
# model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
# model.add(Dense(1))

inp = Input(shape = (1, look_back), name = "Input")
#od_tensor = K.variable([od])
#inp2 = Input(tensor = od_tensor)
x = LSTM(4)([inp, od])
out = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inp, out)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Within the call() function of LSTM layer, I want to check, if the function is getting the inputs, so the code will be like below:

```
  def call(self, inputs, mask=None, training=None, initial_state=None):
    print("inputs[0]: ", inputs[0])
    print("inputs[1]: ", inputs[1])
    inputs_0 = inputs[0]
    self._maybe_reset_cell_dropout_mask(self.cell)
    return super(LSTM, self).call(
        inputs_0, mask=mask, training=training, initial_state=initial_state)
```

The data structure will not change at any point during training, but will be used for some other processing purpose. Is there a way to get this working by passing the dictionary to the call function? How can this data structure be converted to tensor format?

Comment: Read the docs to find out what it requires.  My guess is a `tensor` or numpy that can be converted to one.  Don't try to get around those requirements.

Comment: An LSTM expects a specific tensor shape, not a Dict, what exactly is the layer supposed to do with a dictionary?

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.LSTM` expects inputs: A 3D tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`.For more details about the library refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM)